# Quadratic Form Positive Semi Definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Let's suppose we have a matrix X, and let's suppose it is positive semi-definite. Then, let's write down: a^tXa, where a is a column vector from a unitary matrix A.

In this case: Is the result still semi definite ? If yes, why ? If no, why ?

Thank !

Comment: What's your notion of "positive semidefiniteness" for the restriction of a function to a finite number of vectors?

Comment: Can you clarify, please? If $X$ and $a$ are fixed, what quadratic form are we talking about?

Comment: Since $a \ne 0$ and $X$ is positive semi-definite, we have $a^tXa \ge 0$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I see your point. I have changed the question accordingly

Comment: @max_Zorn I see your point, I reformulated the question.

Comment: Personally, I don't see a difference between the two fomulations, unless you are under the impression that "semi-definite" is synonymous with "greater or equal to $0$" (it is not). In which case, you are asking "Is it true that if $P(X,v)$ holds for all vectors $v$, and I consider some vectors, then $P(X,a)$ holds for all the vectors $a$ I've considered?".

Comment: Well, one way to interpret the question is this: the result of $a^T X a$ is a scalar. If we apply the definition of positive-semidefiniteness of $n \times n$ matrices to $n=1$ we find that a "$1 \times 1$ matrix" is positive semidefinite if and only if it is $\geq 0$. Since $a^T X a \geq 0$ for any $a$ when $X$ is positive semi-definite, this interpretation of the question would lead to a "yes".

Comment: @Florian Yes, this is exactly what I wanted to ask ! Thanks a lot. I don't understand why $a^TXa$ is necessarily  >=0, if X is positive semidefinite ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Please have a look at the interpretation of the question by Florian. Thanks !

Comment: @james: Depends on how you define a positive semi-definite matrix then. One of the standard definitions is "a symmetric $n \times n$ real matrix $M$ is said to be positive semi-definite if the scalar $z^T M z$ is non-negative for every non-zero column vector $z$". If you use this, it follows from the definition. If you use another one you need to tell us which one.